# Fatal error: JApplicationCms::getUserState()

Tags: joomla-3.x, update, front-end, phpmyadmin, localhost

I was trying to update my Joomla 3 site to the 3.2 stable release via Extension manager on localhost, but after installing it, I got a white screen when I try to access the back and the front-end. I've changed the error reporting in the configuration to maximum, and I got this error showing:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe an active session (not closed properly) in the Joomla! sessions table is the error.

Try this:

1. Login to cPanel.
2. Access the database using PHPmyAdmin.
3. Delete all the user sessions from the sessions table.